# Chaining .filter() into a function to load local JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

I'm rendering local JSON data ("Categories") and duplicate ones are being shown. I'm attempting to use `.filter()` with the two other methods (`.sort()` and `.map()`) and I can't remove the duplicates. Does something in my code look off?

#### JS snippet:

```
var testjson = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "Title": "Aardvark",
      "Category": "Animals",
      "Description": "My Test description",
      "TopTrainingCourse": false,
      "ID": 1,
      "Modified": "2019-03-05T20:13:46Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-05T20:13:36Z"
    }, {
      "Title": "Red Panda",
      "Category": "Animals",
      "Description": "Donec id dictum sem",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 10,
      "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z"
    }, {
      "Title": "Tennis",
      "Category": "Sports",
      "Description": "Mauris sagittis ligula",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 11,
      "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z"
    }]
  }
}

 loadAllCourses() {
   let jsonRes = testjson.d.results
     .filter((elem, index, self) => {
        return (index === self.indexOf(elem));
     })
     .sort(function(a,b) { // sorts alphabetically
        return (a.Category > b.Category) ? 1 : ((b.Category > a.Category) ? -1 : 0)
     })
     .map(x => {
        return {
          "Category": x.Category,
          "Title": x.Title
        }
     });

    let curIndex = 0;
    $.each(jsonRes, function(idx, val) {

    $(".form-control").append("<option><div data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal-id\">" + val.Category + "</div></option>") // dropdown
```

Comment: I don't understand the questions - why should `.filter` be chained or not - as in according to *what*? And how does `.filter` have an effect on `.map` to make it obsolete?

Comment: Did you copy and paste this script? Your third object in the array is missing its beginning brace. Also, I would check the value of `self`. I'm pretty sure it defaults to `window`

Comment: @Kramb The brace is missing in this code sample but not in my code. I'll fix it now

Comment: @VLAZ my questions were pretty unclear so I clarified things in my question body. Basically I'm unable to remove the duplicate Categories and I wondered if the problem was caused by chaining `.filter()` to `.sort()` or not.

Comment: @Kramb `self` is the array - it's passed in as the third parameter to the `.filter` callback. And I don't think it's ever `windows` - the value of `this` *could* be `window` but `self` is not automatically assigned - it's merely frequently used to trap the value of `this` to the correct context.

Comment: @Bodrov well, `.filter` returns a new array, so chaining doesn't actually matter to the result if your predicate is correct. And this one isn't because two different objects are always going to be inequal. In fact, there is nothing to suggest any of these is repeated - the data they have seems unique. What do you expect to be filtered?

Comment: @Bodrov What do you expect as the result of your function in snippet above?

Comment: @lankovova Unique categories, in this case [Animals, Sports].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, filter does not work as you expected.
to make it work as you want, change it to:

```
.filter((elem, index, self) => {
  return (index === self.map(el => el.Category).indexOf(elem.Category));
})
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I didn't expect to include `.map()` a second time there.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest solution is to extract `Category` prop using map. Check out code below.

Also there is another way to remove duplicates from array using ES6 Set like this `uniq = [...new Set(array)]`

```js
var testjson = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "Title": "Aardvark",
      "Category": "Animals",
      "Description": "My Test description",
      "TopTrainingCourse": false,
      "ID": 1,
      "Modified": "2019-03-05T20:13:46Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-05T20:13:36Z"
    }, {
      "Title": "Red Panda",
      "Category": "Animals",
      "Description": "Donec id dictum sem",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 10,
      "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z"
    }, {
      "Title": "Tennis",
      "Category": "Sports",
      "Description": "Mauris sagittis ligula",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 11,
      "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z"
    }]
  }
}

const res = testjson.d.results
  .map((obj) => obj.Category)
  .filter((elem, index, self) => index === self.indexOf(elem))
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55129622/3982562) (although simple) loops more than necessary.

- The answer loops through the list with `filter`. (1 full iteration)
- For each list item the list is mapped to the category. (full iterations equal to the amount of items in the list)
- The mapped values are then searched for a specific value using `indexOf`. (partial iterations equal to the amount of items in the list)

With your example data (3 elements) you end up iterating the same list 1 + 3 + 3 * 0.5 = 5.5 times. (Using an average of 0.5 iteration for `indexOf`). Let me up the scale of the list for you. Let's say you have a list of 10 items. Now you're iterating the list 1 + 10 + 10 * 0.5 = 16 times. This can be reduced by doing the category map before hand and referring to the same list each time.

```js
var testjson = { "d": { "results": [{ "Title": "Aardvark", "Category": "Animals", "Description": "My Test description", "TopTrainingCourse": false, "ID": 1, "Modified": "2019-03-05T20:13:46Z", "Created": "2019-03-05T20:13:36Z" }, { "Title": "Red Panda", "Category": "Animals", "Description": "Donec id dictum sem", "TopTrainingCourse": true, "ID": 10, "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z", "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z" }, { "Title": "Tennis", "Category": "Sports", "Description": "Mauris sagittis ligula", "TopTrainingCourse": true, "ID": 11, "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z", "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z" }] } }

console.log(
  testjson.d.results
    .filter(
      function (elem, index) { return index === this.indexOf(elem.Category) },
      testjson.d.results.map(el => el.Category) // <= executes only once
    )
);
```

With the above code reduce iteration to 1 + 1 + 10 * 0.5 = 7 times (for a list of 10).

However this can be done even faster by using a lookup object.

```js
var testjson = { "d": { "results": [{ "Title": "Aardvark", "Category": "Animals", "Description": "My Test description", "TopTrainingCourse": false, "ID": 1, "Modified": "2019-03-05T20:13:46Z", "Created": "2019-03-05T20:13:36Z" }, { "Title": "Red Panda", "Category": "Animals", "Description": "Donec id dictum sem", "TopTrainingCourse": true, "ID": 10, "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z", "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z" }, { "Title": "Tennis", "Category": "Sports", "Description": "Mauris sagittis ligula", "TopTrainingCourse": true, "ID": 11, "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z", "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z" }] } }

console.log(
  testjson.d.results
    .filter(function (elem) {
      return !this[elem.Category] && (this[elem.Category] = true);
    }, {})
);
```

The above loops only once though the array itself and then uses an lookup object to store and check the presence of other elements within the array. This reduces iteration to 1 time. Keep in mind that the above method does use a plain JavaScript object. Meaning that categories cannot contain reserved properties, like `constructor`. If this is an issue you can pre- or suffix your categories during the check. Here is an example:

```
!this['_!!_' + elem.Category] && (this['_!!_' + elem.Category] = true)
```

**Note that the above usage of the `function` keyword is intentional.** [Arrow function don't have their own `this` binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and therefore cannot be used in combination with a second argument in the `filter` method.